# Call Microsoft Excel APIs from a custom function using Excel built-in functions?

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I successfully called my First Microsoft Excel API from a custom function thanks to this link [Call Microsft Excel APIs from a custom function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/call-excel-apis-from-custom-function#feedback). However, I am trying to add the VLOOKUP built-in Excel function inside of my custom function. After attempting multiple things for the my code to work, I still am getting a #VALUE! in the cell. What is my code missing? I know this is brand new to production as of 5/11 so is this feature not available yet?

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 * @param firstName person's first name
 **/
export async function getRangeValue (firstName: string) {
    let lastName;
    let context = new Excel.RequestContext();
    const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1:C5");
    range.load();
    await context.sync();
    lastName = context.workbook.functions.vlookup(firstName, range, 3, false);
    lastName.load('value');
    await context.sync();
    return lastName.value;
}
```

[image]

```
=CONTOSOSHARE.GETRANGEVALUE("Happy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two calls in the function, please consider to use Exce.run. For example:

```
export async function getRangeValue (firstName: string) {
let lastName;
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1:B5");
    range.load();
    await context.sync();
    lastName = context.workbook.functions.vlookup("Happy", range, 2, false);
    lastName.load("value");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(lastName.value);
  });
return lastName.value;
}
```

Please let me know if it works.